# Angular js posting object to web API is null

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, boolean, http-post

I am posting form data to webAPI and one of object has boolean value(i.e from checkbox; Deviceselected has boolean values here in code).this object returns null in my api controller. 
I tried declaring Desktop and Mobile as string in controller.That did not fix as well.
What am i missing in here?

*I'm able to post other data except Deviceselected*

**Angualrjs controller code**

```
 $scope.SendData = function (Data) {
            var GetAll = new Object();
            GetAll.Redirection = Data.redirection;
            GetAll.Deviceselected = new Object();
            GetAll.Deviceselected.Desktop =  Data.devSelected.desktop;
                GetAll.Deviceselected.Mobile = Data.devSelected.mobile;
            GetAll.Protocol = Data.protocol;
                 $http({
                    url: "http://localhost:61352/api/Market",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: GetAll,
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    }
                }).then(successCallback, errorCallback);

            };
        })
```

**Web API code**

```
public class SubmitData
{
    public string Redirection { get; set; }
    public Deviceselected deviceSelected;
    public string Protocol { get; set; }
}

public class Deviceselected
{
    public Boolean Desktop { get; set; }
    public Boolean Mobile { get; set; }
}
[HttpPost]
public string sendData(HttpRequestMessage  request,[FromBody] SubmitData marketModel)
{
    return "Data Reached";
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us values of ``Data`` object?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it works with the same logic.1)Cleared cache 2)Run API and then load HTML